# Line breaks not working on second Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll

So, I have been using Jekyll with no problems for awhile now. I just decided to create my second site on Jekyll, so I used the terminal to create a new site.

The only problem is, for some reason, my Markdown is not working on the second site, yet it works on the first.

My linebreaks are not working. I have to use P tags if I want line breaks, otherwise all the text is kept together even if I use a new line.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have a code repository to help spot the problem ?

Comment: I have it installed on my mac, not sure how to use a repository

Comment: Try https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I just want my damn line breaks. I created a repository but have ZERO idea how to upload my site to it. https://github.com/tango4cash/danhenry

Comment: Ok I am really not interested in doing this, it's just more stuff I will have to learn and more problems to arise. Jekyll is bad enough by itself. Is there any way to find the problem?

Comment: You just have to install git and learn how to use the desktop app, which is like a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok I am really not interested in doing this, it's just more stuff I will have to learn and more problems to arise. Jekyll is bad enough by itself. Is there any way to find the problem?

You might want to try https://jekyllcodex.org. It contains a workflow for people who want to use Jekyll but do not want to touch the command line.